# Why is MS forcing me into an asynchronous operation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, storagefile

I need to read a numeric value (a version number) from a text file in my resources.
I compare this version number to the version number of an installed component.
If the version number in the resources is higher than the installed version, I copy the new component (a database) from my resources to a local directory where the user can use it.

I need to do this synchronously because my application can't work without the database.

However, I don't see any way to do it synchronously.
MS forces me to do it with an async task like this:

```
private async Task<string> ResourcesReadTextFile(string uFileName)
{
    string sRet = "";

    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(cstAssets + uFileName));
        using (var inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var classicStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(classicStream))
        {
            while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                sRet = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Assert(false);//check here
    }
    return sRet;
}
```

Now I've encountered a situation where the app started before the database was copied over to the local directory as the copying also needs to be done asynchronously, there simply isn't any way to do it synchronous.
There is no such function as StorageFile.Copy().

What I'm therefore using is:

```
private async void pCopyFromResourcesToLocal(string uFileName)
{
    // Cant await inside catch, but this works anyway
    try
    {
        StorageFile storfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(cstAssets + uFileName));
        await storfile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

This drives me crazy.

People write that Async should be embraced and hugged and appreciated, but in my case it causes nothing but trouble.

I don't see any way of making this thing synchronous, and I wonder why MS forces me to do it that way.

Any help very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Code as a screenshot:

[image]

Edit: I've added the top methods here:

```
    public static async Task<DB> InitAppDb()
    {
        IFileHelper helper = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>();
        string path = await helper.GetFilePathAndCopyFromResourcesIfNotPresent("tablet.db");

        return (_dbApp = new DB(path));
    }

    public async Task CopyDatabaseIfNotExists(string uFileName)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile nExpectedFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        bool bCopyNewDB = false;

        Task<bool> datatask = pResourceIsNewer(uFileName);
        bCopyNewDB = await datatask;

        if (! bCopyNewDB)
        {
            try
            {
                await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(uFileName); //nExpectedFolder.GetFileAsync(dbPath);/// ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("preinstalledDB.db");
                // No exception means it exists
                return;
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                // The file obviously doesn't exist
            }
        }

        pCopyFromResourcesToLocal(uFileName);

    }

    private async Task<bool>pResourceIsNewer(string uPath)
    {
        string sFileNameAppDBVersion =uPath + ".txt";

        if (IsolatedStorageFileExist(sFileNameAppDBVersion))
        {
            int iAppDBVersionInstalled = Convert.ToInt32(IsolatedStorageReadTextFile(sFileNameAppDBVersion));

            Task<string> datatask = ResourcesReadTextFile(sFileNameAppDBVersion);
            string s = await datatask;

            int iAppDBResources = Convert.ToInt32(s);

            bool b = (iAppDBResources > iAppDBVersionInstalled);
            return b;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You appear to be confusing synchronous with parallell. It doesn't matter that this code runs asynchronously, the code calling it will only continue to the next statement after this method finishes.

Comment: That `async  void` is a dangerous trick and the real cause of your problems. Show where/how you need to call this. Is the top  method awaitable?

Comment: You are complaining that MS forces you into good programming practices? Also, it's not MS problem that you don't know how `async/await` works

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've added it.

Comment: "Synchronous" doesn't mean "execute things at the same time as other things". It means the opposite of that. If anything, the availability of `async` methods are _helpful_ for what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is not about 'MS'. JavaScript, Flash and many new platforms abolish  synchronus I/O. About time.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Camilo, now (after several days and more experience) I understand your comment and could use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
//private async void pCopyFromResourcesToLocal(string uFileName) { ... }
  private async Task pCopyFromResourcesToLocal(string uFileName) { ... }
```

and then you can await it:

```
//pCopyFromResourcesToLocal(uFileName);
  await pCopyFromResourcesToLocal(uFileName);
```

and it will all be completed before you call `return (_dbApp = new DB(path));`

Nothing in this `async`/`await` chain can happen out of order.

Comment: Thank you so much, let me please test it before I accept, ok?

Comment: OMG, you don't know how much worth you explanation was, thank you so much. Does this mean that when I start something async, I need to await just anything? And my code was failing because I used something synchronously / didn't await something down the line?

Comment: Would I be allowed to say this?         private async Task<bool>pCopyFromResourceToLocalIfResourceIsNewer(string uPath)
        {
  await pSomethingA();
  await pSomethingB();

                return true;
         }

Answer (score 1):

When you say that your app can't work without the database, remember that using an await keyword does just that, so the following line of code will not execute until after the async call returns.  You can structure your code such that it is responsive while you wait for the DB to come back online.

However, you can force your function to be synchronous by using a construct such as:

```
StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(cstAssets + uFileName)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Or, even better, have a look at the [JoinableTaskFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.joinabletaskfactory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017).

Comment: Thank you, but my database contains all the translations for the menus, etc. It's necessary to have it loaded right away.

Comment: That's fine - you could simply display a "Loading" screen until you were ready.  If you force it to be synchronous, your app will appear to "stall" while you go to the DB.  If you do decide that you would like to go down this route, I would strongly advise using the JTF, otherwise you're liable to end up with deadlocks.

Answer (score -1):

Any asynchronous API method can be made synchronous by simply tagging `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the end, as @pm_2 says.

In the case of `Task<T>` results, you can simply use `.Result`, and for `Task` results, `.Wait()`.

You can either write an asynchronous function to read your file, then wait for its result at the top level, or you can write a synchronous method and wait for the result of every call it makes to async functions.

So Microsoft is not forcing you into anything: it's just providing a simpler API with the lowest common denominator of both asynchronous and synchronous workflows.

Comment: "... an be made synchronous" - Yes, but that is the wrong direction.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm trying to answer the question of why there is no `StorageFile.Copy()` here.

Comment: I don't think that is the "why" here. Note that .Wait and .Result should not be called on the GUI thread, they could deadlock.